# Add elements to the maximum values of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, maximum, partitions

Hi i have a list of n elements and i want to know the 30 maxim values of list without changing his order. And suppose that i have a second list with n elements and i want to add this elements to the previous list but just to the 30 ones that have the maximum values, and also without changing his order. How i can do this? This is the code that i use to add elements to other list but i don´t know how to do it in the way that i explain before.

```
plotData = Partition[Riffle[informacion1, desvi], 2]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out `Ordering` in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

To find the 30 largest of your first list, we'll call it `list1`, use

```
TakeLargest[lis1,30]
```

To then add only to these largest from the second list, let's call it `list2`, we can use `Ordering` to identify the positions where the 30 largest are.

```
list3=list1;
(list3[[#]] = list1[[#]] + list2[[#]]) &@Ordering[list1, -30]
```

Then `list3` will contain a copy of `list1` with only the desired elements changed.

---

**Edit:** A small demo.

```
list1 = RandomInteger[1000, 10]
list2 = RandomInteger[1000, 10]
list3 = list1;
(list3[[#]] = list1[[#]] + list2[[#]]) &@Ordering[list1, -4];
list3

Sort[list1]
Sort[list3]
```

> `{383, 226, 192, 397, 565, 60, 184, 535, 423, 77}
>   {667, 297, 386, 866, 625, 881, 233, 327, 288, 411}
>   {383, 226, 192, 1263, 1190, 60, 184, 862, 711, 77}`
>
> `{60, 77, 184, 192, 226, 383, 397, 423, 535, 565}
>   {60, 77, 184, 192, 226, 383, 711, 862, 1190, 1263}`

Notice only the 4 largest in `list1` see their values change in `list3`, while the order is retained.

Comment: Or `(list3[[#]] += list2[[#]]) &@Ordering[list1, -4];`

Comment: @belisarius Ah yes, the compound operator. If only Matlab hadn't broken me of expecting such a convenience in computational software, I'd be much better at remembering it's available in Mathematica. D=

Answer (score 1):

As  N.J.Evans hinted you can do the first part with [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html).  I'll take the largest seven instead of 30 for brevity, and use n = 20.  First generate sample data:

```
n = 20;
p = 7;
SeedRandom[0]
list = RandomInteger[99, 20]
```

> ```
> {83, 66, 4, 21, 71, 67, 16, 67, 76, 28, 21, 43, 17, 46, 53, 84, 85, 17, 50, 15}
> ```

Find the places of the largest seven values:

```
m = Ordering[list, -p]
```

> ```
> {6, 8, 5, 9, 1, 16, 17}
> ```

Sort that list of places to keep them in order:

```
m = Sort[m]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 16, 17}
> ```

Extract the values from `list`:

```
list[[m]]
```

> ```
> {83, 71, 67, 67, 76, 84, 85}
> ```

I am not sure I follow the second part of the question but I *think* this does what you want:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list2 = RandomInteger[99, 20]
```

> ```
> {80, 14, 0, 67, 3, 65, 23, 97, 68, 74, 15, 24, 4, 90, 83, 70, 1, 30, 48, 25}
> ```

```
m2 = Sort @ Ordering[list2, -p]
```

> ```
> {1, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16}
> ```

```
list2[[m2]]
```

> ```
> {80, 97, 68, 74, 90, 83, 70}
> ```

```
list3 = list;
list3[[m]] = {list3[[m]], list2[[m2]]}\[Transpose];

list3
```

> ```
> {{83, 80}, 66, 4, 21, {71, 97}, {67, 68}, 16, {67, 74}, {76, 90},
>   28, 21, 43, 17, 46, 53, {84, 83}, {85, 70}, 17, 50, 15}
> ```

[`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) if desired:

```
list3 // Flatten
```

> ```
> {83, 80, 66, 4, 21, 71, 97, 67, 68, 16, 67, 74, 76, 90,
>  28, 21, 43, 17, 46, 53, 84, 83, 85, 70, 17, 50, 15}
> ```